# How to call my own php page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Hi i have create my own events pages in php. i want to customize all those page in magento.

for example create_events.php is one of the page which is created by me.i want to call this page when user clicks the create event in left menu after logged in.

Left menu:
create event
view event
delete event

I don't know how to call these php page in magento1.7 and where to place these page to make it work in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a good practice, you can achieve it by making one controller which will be called once you click on `Create Event`, and include the `create_event.php` inside it. Again, not at all good practice and highly not recommended.

Comment: how to make  controller???Actually i don't know what do you mean.Am newbie to magento.I have created every pages .My work is to call all those pages and make it function.

Comment: pls check this.. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento